# How to Reindex Solr in Production with Data Changes/Updates

Tags: indexing, solr, load-balancing, solrcloud, reindex

I have deployed Solr in Solrcloud mode (Operator) and although I am pretty good with K8s I am fairly new to Solr. I have worked with nosql darabases but Solr interests me and so I deployed it in my lab.

Now I am going through different architectural use cases and want to underdtand (Re) Indexing in Solr and the use of aliases and how LBs might make it easier in production.

So I have a collection with one core (all fields stored and indexed) (basic case). Now lets assume I want to replicate a scenario like a hot swap in production. Now I would create two aliases (a and b) and point alias a to the productive search collection. I would then create a second alias (b) and reindex into a seperate collection (with its own core) and swap the aliases to the reindexed collection.
My question:

1. Is the process ok? I have a problem underdtanding the concept of collections, cores and indexes and how they interplay. Or do I reindex into a seperate core but in the same collection?.
2. In the above scenario, what if during the reindexing iperation the productive collection gets updates? Isnt the data after the switch not out-of-sync? In this use case which certainly happens all the time, I wouldnt want the request to run into empty queries or lost data.
3. How might a LB make the process easier? 2nd solrcloud cluster?